# How to encrypt and decrypt connection string in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, encryption, entity-framework-5

I want to encrypt connection string and decrypt while using it in Entity Framework 5.

What I did that I had my connection string as

```
<add name="HContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I had encrypted this connection has below

```
string encryptedString = KimberlyClark.EuroCRM.Encryption.Encrypt(encryptedString, "mykey");
```

And after that I had copied encrypted string to my web.config file and used like below

```
public class HContext : DbContext
{
    public HContext()
        : base("HContext") 
    {
        string encryptedString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HContext"].ConnectionString;
        string connectString = KimberlyClark.EuroCRM.Encryption.Decrypt(encryptedString, "mykey");
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectString;
    }

}
```

But I am getting below error inside constructor

**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code that, you did not encrypt your connection string.
Check this line:

```
string encryptedString = KimberlyClark.EuroCRM.Encryption.Encrypt(encryptedString, "mykey");
```

You should to pass a parameter that your connection string, not encryptedString variable.

Comment: Hi had already encrypted and copied that string to web.config

Comment: Could you check decrypted connection string? What is the result after decryption?

Comment: after decryptn i'm getting this string "Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: Ok. So there is not an encryption error. Probably your connection string is invalid. Please check this address: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I got it worked by changing connectionstring name from HContext to HKContext.

Comment: I could not understand what is the solution?

Comment: I'm using code first approach my dbcontext class name was same with connection string name attribute so i had changed that name attribute and it got worked don't know how it's working